# Remove non digit part of data in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and i cant update it for some reasons.
i have some data in one column in a table which has bad data.
this column (lets call it postfix) should only have digits but because of bad PHP validation now it has some non digit character in it. because the characters can be anything i cant just replace some specific character like what we may do for phone number.

I found a way to do that in MySQL 8.0.4 by using `REGEXP_REPLACE` function like this `REGEXP_REPLACE(postfix, '[^0-9]', '')` in update query but i cant use it in MySQL 5.7.
 
Is there any simple alternative way in MySQL 5.7?

Comment: This is a one-time task, right? export, clear, then import back.

Comment: actually this project is running on some servers with symfony platform and i want to fix it with a symfony mysql migration to fix it for all of them by just running one migration.